# issues printing last error message in php

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database using PHP, but I am getting 32767 error reporting in the console. I tried to show the error message using `echo error_reporting()`  but it is not showing the error message.

Here is the code:

```
$name = $_POST[name];
$topic = $_POST[topic];
$tell = $_POST[tell];
$birthDay = $_POST[birthDay];
$job = $_POST[job];
$email = $_POST[email];
$lastMajor = $_POST[lastMajor];
$major = $_POST[major];
$add = $_POST[add];
$today = "test";

$connectionString = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","myDB");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($connectionString,"INSERT INTO coWork (topic , name , tell , birthDay , job , email , lastMajor , major, add , date )
     VALUES ('$topic', '$name','$tell','$birthDay','$job' , '$email' , '$lastMajor' , '$major' , '$add' , '$today')");

mysqli_close($connectionString);
echo error_reporting();
```

How can I get the content of the error message?

Comment: `error_reporting` doesn't report errors, it sets/gets error reporting _level_.

Comment: I don't think I can explain it better than [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Georg ,thanks for the link , of course u can't ;)
i read that , how should i know what does 32767 means , as it being reported in the browser when i run the code ?!!

Comment: Also look at [Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php). You'll see that 32767 is E_ALL. (PHP 5.4)

Comment: I don't get it :-?
when i run this , in the browser 32767 shows , and the record is not in my DB
is there any way that i can track it to get whats going on ?!!!!
as i looked again , when i set error reporting level to 32767 it shows any error that happens on the browser , is that true ? if so why record is not saved in the DB , and there isn't any error reporting on the browser page ?!!!!!

Comment: `error_reporting` `[...]Returns the old error_reporting level or the current level if no level parameter is given.[...]`  `[...]The available error level constants and the actual meanings of these error levels are described in the predefined constants.[...]` (the link _bitWorking_  gave you)

Comment: what is the reason you are trying to echo error_reporting() function ? read about the function, this isn't the way you should use it.

Comment: as i looked again , when i set error reporting level to 32767 it shows any error that happens on the browser , is that true ? if so why record is not saved in the DB , and there isn't any error reporting on the browser page ?!!!!!
OK , Then , i don't echo the return value of the error reporting function , but still i can't save the record into DB

Comment: `E_ALL`(32767)  reports all php related errors (wether this will be in the browser or just in a log file depends on the settings). Anyway a php code that does not report an error does not guarantee that e.g. a row is inserted into the database. You need to check the error message of you mysql connection [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`error_reporting()` => `Sets which PHP errors are reported`

To get/handle errors you have to use functions like [error_get_last](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) or [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

In your case you want to get the MySql error, so you have to use [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) or [mysqli_errno](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php)

```
if (!mysqli_query($connectionString, 'INSERT ...')) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connectionString));
}
```

Like Quentin noted you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. So please use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: it was really use full i got it , but now that i change the code to what you said , i get 1064 error number , which means syntax error , any idea where I'm being wrong ?

Comment: @Majidkhalili probably you have some bad characters in your post vars. This is another reason to better use `mysqli_real_escape_string` or `mysqli_prepare`

Comment: i finally find the reason , it was because of the add column , i just changed it to address and everything works fine ;
Thanks all guys ;)